# servlet life cycle

Tags: java, servlets

How servlet life cycle happens in servlet engine.

when servlet init()  service() destroy() methods calls in servlet engine.

can you please explain the **servlet life cycle in java**

Comment: Read _Head First Servlets and JSP_ also Google search leads to lakhs of results

Comment: Grab a copy of good book on `JSP and Servlets` and your doubt will be gone ;)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you google your question. It will give you more useful links like [Servlet Life cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html)

, [Java Servlets](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~jniu/teaching/csc31800/notes/0421-Servlets.pdf)